# Where can I see what's fixed in 4.6.15?

Tags: 4.6

The announcement of release 4.6.15 (and previous updates) on the CiviCRM website blog is very 4.7 centric. There's no link to what fixes have been incorporated into the 4.6 update - and as 4.6 is an LTS release many will be wanting to stick with it.  Or have I missed it?  If someone can send me a link here that would be great.  Suggestion: improve the announcement to have a link to the fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed on your suggestion -- the notification post usually does have a link to the fixes.  Here are the issues with a fixed version of 4.6.15:

[CiviCRM issues fixed and closed for 4.6.15](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CRM%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%204.6.15%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Closed%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC)

Comment: Is there any way to back port my 4.7.6 database to 4.6.15?